# Draw histogram and plot using python

Tags: python-2.7

I just started using Python. 
I want to draw firstly an histogram and then a plot from a text file 
this file presents two columns and about 12 millions lines.
this is an example of the file data

```
0.69359481 1
0.64862049 1
-1.00000000 5
-0.07840061 1
-0.13079703 1
0.54300547 1
-0.55758357 1
1.00000000 9
0.48491240 1
-0.32764208 1
-0.98689210 1
```

So as you see, the x value is a float ranged from -1.00000000 to 1.00000000
and the y axis is an integer (minimum is 1 maximum can be more than 100000)

I need your help to do so

Thanks

Comment: sorry about the example
 first line is 0.69359481 1
 second line is 0.64862049 1 
third line is -1.00000000 5 
.....

Comment: You want the histogram of your first column and then plot first column vs second column?

Comment: yes
I want to show these data using two methods:
1. Histogram : x axis is the first column and y axis is the second column

2. Plot :  x axis is the first column and y axis is the second column